# Google Chrome Developer Tools Strange Behavior

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My responsive tools are messed up as shown in the picture. Does anyone know how to fix this without resetting everything?

[image: strange chrome dev tool behavior responsive tools]

Comment: I'm missing the obvious but what exactly is messed up here?

Answer (score 0):

It's not messed up. Looks like you have mistakenly clicked on "Toggle device tool bar". Click on that again and you will be back to normal.